# How to pull branch that is called “tag”

Tags: git, branch, git-push, git-pull

I have just begun to work on a new branch that someone has cleverly called `tag`. Now when I try to pull the changes, using:

```
git pull origin tag
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: You need to specify a tag name.
```

Which I can only assume is because `tag` is a keyword... I have tried to use single/double quotes:

```
git pull origin 'tag' then I tried...
git pull origin "tag" then...
git pull origin `tag` ...you get the gist...
git pull origin <tag>
git pull origin \tag
```

to pull but I get the same result.

Is there a method to use that allows you to pull changes from a keyword-named branch?

Comment: *I try to pull the changes, I get [...]* Please edit your question to specify what command you use, exactly.

Comment: Brsowing the source code it does appear that `tag` is an undocumented keyword to `git fetch`.  I'd recommend renaming it, who knows how many other git commands will have similar issues.

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry you were write, I forget not everyone is telepathic :) I had edited the question to reflect the attempts I have made, I forgot to mention it earier.

Comment: @AndrewC I would if I could but atm I dont have control over the naming conventions, though I have mentioned this in the morning scrum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git pull <remote> <refspec>
```

Since that second parameter is a *refspec*, you can use the extended syntax to make sure that Git doesn’t try to do something with tags there. The extended syntax is `localbranch:remotebranch`. So if you just want to pull the `tag` branch, you can do this:

```
git pull origin tag:tag
```

The same problem appears with `git push` btw. and can be worked around in the same way:

```
git push origin tag:tag
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  I had NO idea on how to do this!